# Yii custom date format (pattern)

Tags: php, date, yii

Is there a way to specify your own date pattern besides the included ones (small, medium, full). The main point here is that it should work with i18n. I've tried a couple of things but I couldn't get it to work...

```
Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("l d/m/Y",$slide->date_start);
```

I know about `strftime` but the problem here is that different hosting providers use different locale string... and you have to customize it...

I'm looking for an elegant way of doing this.

I'd like to display the date in `l d/m/Y` form...

Update:
Never mind... I've just found out that `dateFormatter` doesn't use standard php date format...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should measure time solely in [`Unix Time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) because Timezones & date formats are a presentation-layer problem. Unix time is always UTC & It's a single number, so easier to pass around in code.

As far the problem of "hosting providers use different locale string", just ask the user his timezone & display according to that. far less error-prone than trying to guess.

For date formatting, have a look at YII's [format()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail)

Hope it answers your question

Comment: As i've said in my update the correct format is `EEEE, d/M/yyyy` which is a little bit different than in standard php...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related [yii forum discussion](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/9792-working-with-datetime-fields-via-activerecord/)

The yii forum solution worked for me to avoid raw SQL `NOW()` statements but still produce database-friendly date strings with  PHP `date()` and `time()` functions which otherwise return integers.

In protected/config/main.php:

```
...
'params'=>array(
    'mysqlDateTimeFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s', # ':u' adds microsecond precision,
...
```

Then, wherever you want to put a date-time string into a model field use

```
$myModel->myDate = date(Yii::app()->params['mysqlDateTimeFormat']);
```

Obviously you can enter the date/time format into the date (or time) functions directly if you prefer.